# How to send email according to spreadsheet dates in google apps script?

Tags: sorting, date, google-apps-script, google-sheets

There are five spreadsheets in google drive folder that send data to one email.

So far all the data from the spreadsheet will be sent to email. How can I sort the spreadsheet by date so that, only last four spreadsheet data will be sent.
These are the names of my spreadsheets: 
1. Dec 2018 Workbook
2. Jan 2019 Workbook
3. Feb 2019 Workbook
4. March 2019 Workbook
5. April 2019 Workbook

```
function checkSalesss(){
  var file, files = 
 DriveApp.getFolderById("17Si9n3Uzf1yF6sGWaT2VygxLfPMnUgrE")
.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS)
  var body = ''; // Added
  var subject = []; // Added
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    file = files.next();
    var activeSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(file);
    var sheets = activeSpreadSheet.getSheets();

    //loop through sheets to look for value
    for (var sheetIndex = 0; sheetIndex < sheets.length; sheetIndex++) {
      var sheet = sheets[sheetIndex];
      var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
      var resultArr = [];

      //To Loop through the whole data Rows
      for (var i=1;i<data.length;i++) {

       //Takes columns from L to S (To loop through the Columns)
        for (var j=11;j<19;j++) {
          var cellVal = data[i][j];
          if (cellVal > 0) {
            resultArr.push([data[i][0],data[0][j],cellVal]);
          }
        }
      }
      if (resultArr.length>0) {
        var spreadsheetName = activeSpreadSheet.getName(); // Added
        subject.push(spreadsheetName); 
        body += "<br>" + "<b>"+ sheet.getName() + "(" + spreadsheetName + 
  ")" + "</b>" + "<br>"; 
        for (var m=0;m<resultArr.length;m++) {
          body+= "For Part No "+resultArr[m][0].toString()+" and Month 
"+resultArr[m][1].toString()+", Value is "+resultArr[m][2].toString()+" 
<br>";
        }
      }
    }
  }

  //send email
  if (subject.length > 0) {
    var s = "Alert " + " " + subject.join(",") + " " + " >6MO"; // Added
   MailApp.sendEmail({to: "abc@gmail.com",subject:"Alert", htmlBody: 
  body}); 
  }
}
```

I want the jan 2019, feb 2019, march 2019, april 2019 spreadsheet data to be sent to the email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to send an email by selecting Spreadsheet depending on the Spreadsheet name.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification point:

- In order to select the Spreadsheet, create an array of `spreadsheetNames` including the Spreadsheet name that you want to select.
- The Spreadsheet is selected using the array. In this case, I add a script of `if (spreadsheetNames.some(function(e) {return e == spreadsheetName})) {}`.

#### Modified script:

```
function checkSales(){
  var spreadsheetNames = [ //  Added
    // "Dec 2018 Workbook", // This was commented out. So the following 4 Spreadsheets are used for creating the data.
    "Jan 2019 Workbook",
    "Feb 2019 Workbook",
    "March 2019 Workbook",
    "April 2019 Workbook"
  ];

  var file, files = DriveApp.getFolderById("17Si9n3Uzf1yF6sGWaT2VygxLfPMnUgrE").getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
  var body = '';
  var subject = [];
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    file = files.next();
    var activeSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(file);
    var spreadsheetName = activeSpreadSheet.getName(); // Added
    if (spreadsheetNames.some(function(e) {return e == spreadsheetName})) { // Added
      var sheets = activeSpreadSheet.getSheets();
      for (var sheetIndex = 0; sheetIndex < sheets.length; sheetIndex++) {
        var sheet = sheets[sheetIndex];
        var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
        var resultArr = [];
        for (var i=1;i<data.length;i++) {
          for (var j=11;j<19;j++) {
            var cellVal = data[i][j];
            if (cellVal > 0) {
              resultArr.push([data[i][0],data[0][j],cellVal]);
            }
          }
        }
        if (resultArr.length>0) {
  //        var spreadsheetName = activeSpreadSheet.getName(); // removed
          subject.push(spreadsheetName); 
          body += "<br>" + "<b>"+ sheet.getName() + "(" + spreadsheetName + ")" + "</b>" + "<br>"; 
          for (var m=0;m<resultArr.length;m++) {
            body+= "For Part No "+resultArr[m][0].toString()+" and Month "+resultArr[m][1].toString()+", Value is "+resultArr[m][2].toString()+" <br>";
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  if (subject.length > 0) {
    var s = "Alert " + " " + subject.join(",") + " " + " >6MO"; // Added
    MailApp.sendEmail({to: "abc@gmail.com",subject:"Alert", htmlBody: body}); 
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- About `last four spreadsheet data`, I thought that those might be "Jan 2019 Workbook", "Feb 2019 Workbook", "March 2019 Workbook", "April 2019 Workbook". If you want to modify them, please modify the array of `spreadsheetNames` of the above script.

#### Reference:

- [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks a million. This is what i am looking for.

Comment: @Sriram Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I could correctly understand about your question by the detail information you provided. Thank you, too.

Comment: Is there anyway where we can extract the month and year without defining the name of the file in the script?

Comment: If more spreadsheets added, i need to add the names of the files every time in the script. Is there any possibility to just sort by month and year?

Comment: @Sriram Although I'm not sure whether I could understand your replying, for example, if you want to retrieve the files depending on the modified date, how about using the search query like ``DriveApp.searchFiles("modifiedDate > '2019-06-24T00:00:00'")``? For this information, please check at [searchFiles(params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchfilesparams) and [Search for files and folders](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/search-files).

Comment: yes i tried that but I am trying to retrieve the files depending on the month stated in the file's name. That is not possible right?

Comment: @Sriram I apologize my proposal was not useful for your situation. As other method, for example, how about using the search query like ``title contains 'April'``? In this case, the files of the filename including "April" are retrieved.

Comment: yes that will be useful. Can you help me by showing the updated code? i am new to apps script, therefore I am not sure where  to change.

Comment: @Sriram Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot clearly see the vision of your goal. So I cannot propose the modified script yet. This is due to my poor skill. I apologize for this. If I could correctly understand your goal, I would like to propose the modified script.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have got the solution by using .searchFiles

Comment: @Sriram I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.